# Display data from AJAX call on View (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX call to back-end to get data

Here is back-end code

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EmailsList()
    {
        var itemsEmail = db.InvitationMails
            .Select(x=> new
            {
                Email = x.To.ToString(),
                Name = x.Name.ToString(),
            })
            .ToList();
        return Json(itemsEmail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Here is AJAX call

```
<script>
$('#save_quest').click(function () {
    email_update();
});

function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {

            console.log(result);
            console.log(result.EmailsList);
        }
    });
}
```

It works well.

But if I write  this row `console.log(result.EmailsList);` like this `console.log(result.EmailsList.Email);`

I will get this error

> ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Email' of undefined

How I can get one parameter?

Comment: Your `result` is a collection of objects where each item in the collection contains properties `Email` and `Name` - you need to loop through the array and get the properties of each item (and you do not need to use `.ToString()` when the value is already a `string`). You can also remove the pointless `contentType` and `processData` options

Comment: Result is collection, you need to check that collection to get data

Answer (score 0):

as EmailsList is a list you need to loop through it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.EmailsList.length; i++) {
            //to get email use this
            result.EmailsList[i].Email;
        }
```

If you want to get only first email then you can do it like this:

```
result.EmailsList[0].Email
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` variable is already list .. so you just need to use `result[0].Email`

```
function email_update() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("EmailsList", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result[0].Email);
            console.log(result[0].Name);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this. You can't access property of list directly, you have to change the index to access it.

```
  console.log(result.EmailsList[0].Email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.each( result.EmailsList, function (item, i) {
    alert(item.Email);
})
```